# Scala How to avoid reading the file twice

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-2.8

Here is the sample program I am working on to read a file with list of values one per line. I have to add all these values converting to double and also need to sort the values. Here is what I came up so far and it is working fine.

```
import scala.io.Source

object Expense{

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val lines = Source.fromFile("c://exp.txt").getLines()

    val sum: Double = lines.foldLeft(0.0)((i, s) => i + s.replaceAll(",","").toDouble)
    println("Total => " + sum)


    println((Source.fromFile("c://exp.txt").getLines() map (_.replaceAll(",", "").toDouble)).toList.sorted)

  }

}
```

The question here is, as you can see I am reading the file twice and I want to avoid it. As the `Source.fromFile("c://exp.txt").getLines()` gives you an iterator, I can loop through it only once and next operation it will be null, so I can't reuse the `lines` again for sorting and I need to read from file again. Also I don't want to store them into a temporary list. Is there any elegant way of doing this in a functional way?

Comment: You're already creating an implicit list, so why don't you want to use one? Also, I might consider doing the map where you replaceAll once, and then do subsequent work on that list. Otherwise, you're doing all the replaceAll functions twice too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert it to a `List`, so you can reuse it:

```
val lines = Source.fromFile("c://exp.txt").getLines().toList
```

Comment: Thanks! I re factored to `val lines = Source.fromFile("c://exp.txt").getLines().toList map (_.replaceAll(",", "").toDouble)`

Comment: Could you please explain how to do reverse sort( i mean descending)?

Comment: This is one way: List(5.2, 2.1, 3.0, 1.3).sorted(Ordering.Double.reverse)

Answer (score 3):

As per my comment, convert it to a list, and rewrite as follows

```
import scala.io.Source

object Expense{

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val lines = Source.fromFile("c://exp.txt").getLines() map (_.replaceAll(",","").toDouble)

    val sum: Double = lines.foldLeft(0.0)((i, s) => i + s)
    println("Total => " + sum)
    println(lines.toList.sorted)

}
```

}

Comment: Yes, actually thats what I ended up with, with a slight modification, `val lines = Source.fromFile("c://exp.txt").getLines().toList map (_.replaceAll(",", "").toDouble)`